# webdriver io click hyperlink by text under specific class

Tags: jquery, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<tr id="LO_header_row" class="lo_row>
  <td class="LO_header" data-assoc="TITLE">
    <a href="Modules.php?modname=Scheduling/Courses.php&subject_id=001&page=1&LO_direction=1&LO_search=&LO_sort=TITLE">Course 12345</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="LOy_row1" class="lo_row>
  <td class="LO_field">
    <a href="Modules.php?modname=Scheduling/Courses.php&include_top=&subject_id=001">Course 12345</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Hi all. I'm using webdriver IO and I'm trying to navigate to the 2nd link using a selector via clicking. I don't really have much options here besides using something like $('a=Course 12345').click(); in order to navigate to the page. But obviously that returns 2 options. I was wondering what the best way to click the page is? Lots of other stuff on the page share the same classes / ID's (since it is list output) I was trying something like $('.LO_field [a=Course 12345]') but clearly that doesn't work. Any help? Open to alternative suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an xpath expression.

```
//td[@class='LO_field']/a[contains(text(), 'Course 12345')]
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try below xpath

```
.//tr[@id='LOy_row1']/td/a
```

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.